# OCaml - Why are Array reference be default

Tags: ocaml

I know that in OCaml we can't change the value of a variable by default. For example we can't do the following :

```
let a = 1;
a = 2;
```

In order to do so we add the keyword `ref` :

```
let a = ref 1; a := 2;
```

Yet what I don't understand is that we don't need to do so for Array. We can change the value of an array even if it's type is not : `ref 'a`.
For example I can do :

```
let a = Array.create 3 0; a.(1) <- 2;
```

Without getting any error.

So is there a reason why we can change the value of an Array without using a reference ?

Also what is the difference between `ref and`mutable` ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In brief, mutable fields come first, before references. Indeed, the reference type is not a primitive type in OCaml. It is defined as

```
type 'a myref = { mutable contents: 'a}
let ref x = { contents=x }
let (!) r = r.contents
let (:=) r x = r.contents <- x
```

(see also http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#1_References )

Thus the primitive building block for mutable values in OCaml are mutable fields not references. Similarly, all fields of an array are mutable by design.